# MySQL Reciprocal Search

Tags: mysql, graph, large-data

I have a table which stores the edges of a directed graph like so:

```
Table EDGES
  FROM_NODE | TO_NODE | STRENGTH
  1         | 1       | 8
  1         | 2       | 5
  2         | 1       | 4
  1         | 3       | 2
  3         | 4       | 1
```

And I'm trying to search for edges which are supported in both directions with strength > 3. In the example above, 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 both exist, however, 1 <-> 3 does not exist in both directions. 1 -> 1 doesn't count, for obvious reasons.

The major complication is that there are over 1,000,000 edges to search, and all the queries I have tried so far fail before I can check if they've worked.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: mysql doesn't support recursive queries (e.g. postgres' "connect by prior"). this is something you'd have to do as a stored procedure, or externally in a client app.

Comment: Have you tried calling `EXPLAIN` on your queries? Can you share information on indices set for you table?

Comment: Post some of the queries you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the most straightforward solution is something like:

```
select one.from_node, one.to_node 
from edges one 
join edges other on (one.to_node = other.from_node AND one.from_node = other.to_node)
where one.strength > 3 AND other.strength > 3
    AND one.from_node <> one.to_node
```

If you have a lot of data, than it's might be a good idea to reconsider indexes on the table and raise the execution limit.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84965/3) is an sql fiddle to check the query.

Comment: In the end, I created a temporary table with all edges over strength = 3, and used Hari's join method to find the reciprocal results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
select
  least(FROM_NODE, TO_NODE) as n1,
  greatest(FROM_NODE, TO_NODE) as n2
from
  edges
where FROM_NODE<>TO_NODE and nodes.strength>3
group by n1, n2
having count(*)=2
```